# How to embed database into final c# .exe file?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012

I have completed my project in c#. I have used SQL Server Compact database (`.sdf` file). Now, when I compile and run, it works fine. But, how will I be able to run the application in other computers without configuring the connection to database?

[image]

Comment: right click and look at the properties of the sdf file - what is the copy(build type?) status?

Comment: What's the problem with just placing the sdf next to the executable? Are you looking for a setup solution? And don't forget that you need to have the SQL Compact runtime installed on the other machine.

Comment: @0xA3 - "next to the executable" will run into authorization problems. And the runtime is just 1 extra DLL, no problem at all.

Comment: @Sayse: Here's the properties - http://oi42.tinypic.com/wvsw78.jpg
.
0xA3 & HenkHolterman: All I want is just get the exe file, copy it into another computer and just use it. (The application is just adding students name and rollno to the database)

Answer (score 0):

In your App.config file add the following after `</configSections>`:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="NameOfYourConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\student.sdf;Initial Catalog=student; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: @SimonWest Actually, it's not, just not formatted properly. See my edit which fixes it.